# Set the IAM Users to access the ASMX webservice for accessing simpleDB

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created a ASMX .NET web service for add, edit and delete a record in simpleDB. These web services only can access the a particular IAM users or roles. Some IAM users can add a record, some users can edit record etc. The web services like "http://mydomain.com/add.asmx?op=add". How can i given permission to access these web services for a IAM users. Is it possible to create a policy for this??. Please help me.

Comment: Are you asking if you can set an IAM policy to restrict SimpleDB usage, or if you can set one specifically for your web service?  It is currently unclear exactly what you are asking -- please edit your question to include more details of your current progress and where you're stuck.

Comment: I want to restrict the access of web service for a particular IAM user that i have created.